# Ruby on Rails routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuck in a [Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#code-static_page_routes) trying to configure Rails routes.

This is my routes.rb:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/', :to  => 'static_pages#home', :via => :get
  match '/help',:to => 'static_pages#help', :via => :get
  match '/about', :to => 'static_pages#about', :via => :get
  match '/contact', :to => 'static_pages#contact', :via => :get
```

When I try to access "localhost" I get:

> No route matches [GET] "/static_pages/help" Try running rake routes
>   for more information on available routes.

I also tried:

```
match '/', :to  => 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help',:to => 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', :to => 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', :to => 'static_pages#contact'
```

but that gives the same error. It only works when I use:

```
get 'static_pages/about'
```

How can I get localhost to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the following at the end of routes.rb

```
match ':action' => 'static#:action'
```

A request to `/help` will then render `app/views/static/help.html.erb`. Don't forget to create the `static` controller though, even if it's empty.

Comment: i did: SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/', :to  => 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help',:to => 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', :to => 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', :to => 'static_pages#contact'
  match ':action' => 'static#:action'  but it still doesn't work, same problem

Comment: What does `rake routes` print? You might want to put it on www.pastebin.com

Comment: in my case ':action' => 'static_pages#action' and 'static_pages/:action' => 'static_pages#action'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

Comment: SyntaxError , /home/marko/ror/sample_app/config/routes.rb:2: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help' 
                    ^

Comment: im using Rails 3.2.8 and ruby 1.8.7

Comment: yea this syntax doesn't work in ruby 1.8.x. Can U try install newer version of ruby like 1.9.3 ... I hope that there will work

Comment: in my case ':action' => 'static_pages#action' and 'static_pages/:action' => 'static_pages#action', but I cant understand the :to usage It seams I don't need it

Comment: in newer versions, :to is just replace of hash rocket